# What is difference between ttl and maxIdletime in Redisson CacheConfig

Tags: redis, spring-cache, redisson

I tried to refer to documents but still I am not clear between difference between ttl an maxIdleTime in [CacheConfig](http://static.javadoc.io/org.redisson/redisson/3.5.6/org/redisson/spring/cache/CacheConfig.html) class in Redisson.

Can anyone shed some light please?

Answer (score 11):

- **maxIdleTime** enables cached object to be kept in as long as it is requested in periods shorter than maxIdleTime
- **ttl** will make the cached object be invalidated after that many seconds regardless of how many times or when it was requested.

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 4):

set maxIdleTime   = 5s

```
0s  ---- 5s 
set ---- evicted

0s  ---    3s    ---- 8s
set --- set/get  ---- evicted
```

==========================================

set ttl = 5s

```
0s  ---    3s    ---- 5s
set --- set/get  ---- evicted
```